# How to correct indentation for single statement in multiple lines for java in intellij

Tags: java, intellij-idea, indentation

I am trying to get my head around to get correct indentation settings in my intellij. I have tried couple of things from [here](https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/code-style-java.html), but nothing seems to work. As you can see, for the this() constructor, `RecordWriter` and `AmazonS3ClientBuilder` gets indented. I want both of them to be below configProvider. IntelliJ automatically adds the indentation when I add a new parameter to this().

```
    public MysteriousClient(final ConfigurationProvider configProvider) {
        this(configProvider,
                RecordWriter.builder().withTopicPrefix(new DefaultStackNameProvider().getStackName()).build(),
                AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient());
    }
```

This is how I would like it to see:

```
    public MysteriousClient(final ConfigurationProvider configProvider) {
        this(configProvider,
             RecordWriter.builder().withTopicPrefix(new DefaultStackNameProvider().getStackName()).build(),
             AmazonS3ClientBuilder.defaultClient());
    }
```

Comment: The style that you see is the convention, because it's a wrapped single statement. Why, specifically, do you want to go against convention?

Comment: I see that, but the below one looks much cleaner to read. I think, some people have got it to look like that.

Comment: Yes, it's possible, but there is a very good reason to prefer the first (it distinguishes between different meanings for the indentation), and I recommend going with conventions when they're standard even if they're sometimes a bit less appealing. (You should check your formatter settings if you're really set on it.)

Comment: Okay, sounds good. I got a nitpick comment about indentation on my code review. Sounds like debatable topic. I don't have a strong preference either way but second one would look a bit cleaner.

Comment: But again what you said also makes sense. If these are default Intellij settings, there is a good reason for it to be there.

Comment: The easiest example to see where it's useful is when you're wrapping method parameters. Double-indenting the wrapped line makes it much easier to identify where the method body (single-indented) begins. This is similar in many other cases.

Comment: I agree with the OP. The double indentation only suggests something missing to me.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## `Indent` versus `Continuation Indent` settings

Yes, IntelliJ offers indentation settings for continuation of a statement as well as for nested statements.

The default in IntelliJ is a convention used across much of the industry, twice width of indenting for continuation as for nesting.

As others suggested, I too suggest you keep a different setting for continuation versus indenting, as these are two very different situations.

But if you insist, search the indent settings for “continuation”m if I recall correctly.

[image: Screenshot of IntelliJ > Preferences > Editor > Code Style > Java > Tabs and Indents > Indent field, versus Continuation Indent field.]

Comment: What is 'd’intubation' in your answer?

Comment: @Techiee Typo. Fixed. Thanks.

Comment: Continuation indent settings helped. Thanks!